# Adding rows to property list in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to add new keys to a property list (.plist) in XCode however when using right click and selecting **Add Row** in a blank area it doesn't do anything.

There is currently already a Root Key visible, I can only add rows within it. (I would like to get rid of it completely)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get rid of the root of a plist. The root is the container Array or Dictionary that stores all values of the plist.

For example, if you were to have a plist with two Strings @"1" and @"2" as values in the root and you create an array from it, that array would be the same as `@[@"1",@"2"]`;

Also you cannot add anything as a sibling to the Root because then it would be like having two plist files. If you want to create multiple arrays in your plist file, add values to the root and change their type to Array.

Answer (score 0):

Select a row there appears a + button and - button

clicking + adds a row - delete the row

[image]

clicking + gives

[image]

Type in and add

Note : Root is not a removable field.Everything is added under the root field.Root is kept so that retrieving from plist is via that root field

Comment: Why a negative? Please add comments while doing so,in fact it is necessary to improve the answer